# How to set up redirect from http to https with nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, nginx, https

I am fighting with this issue the whole day.
Here's my `nginx.cong`:

```
upstream my_website.co {
      server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server{
      listen 80;
      listen  443 default ssl;
      # return 301 https://www.my_website.co; - I put it here, but it didn't work  

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/my_website.co.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/my_website.co.private.key;

      server_name my_website.co _;

      root /home/deployer/my_website/public;

      location / {
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   CLIENT_IP         $remote_addr;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass http://my_website.co;
          break;
        }
        if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
          return 503;
        }
      }
      # return 301 https://www.my_website.co; - I put it here, but it didn't work
```

Could you help me, please, how to redirect everything from `http` to `https`?

My Rails code:

## ApplicationController

```
before_filter :ensure_domain
APP_DOMAIN = 'www.my_website.co'
  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN && Rails.env != 'development'
      redirect_to "https://#{APP_DOMAIN}#{request.env['REQUEST_PATH']}", :status => 301
    end
  end
```

I'll be grateful for every help, I am lost in here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this in the nginx config file on one of my sites and it works without a problem.  I do not have anything in my ApplicationController to force the redirect either.

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name my_website.co;
            rewrite ^ https://server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.my_website.co;
            rewrite ^ https://server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

server {
            listen       443;
            server_name  my_website.co;
            root /home/deployer/my_website/public;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/my_website.co.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/my_website.co.private.key;

            // rest of your config file below
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this setup and when I run `http://my_website.co`, then it's redirected to `http://my_website.co`. But when I run `http://www.my_website.co`, then I get the error **Welcome to nginx!** . How to get rid of this?

Comment: Update my answer with an additional server directive you can use for www to redirect that as well

Answer (score 0):

The server section you have should only listen to port 443, so remove the port 80 from it in your Nginx configuration. Then add a new server section like this to your Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_site.co;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Then Nginx will redirect everything to SSL version for you. You can remove the code in your ApplicationController.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 We can directly do this in application.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

No Need To play with nginx configuration file.